# JQuery not updating CSS elements after PHP include

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am loading PHP files with JQuery/Ajax.
This is the index.php file where the webpages are called

```
<div class = "view-screen">
  <?php include('home.php'); ?>
</div>
```

Depending on which nav link is clicked, that page will display without refreshing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // ...
  $navLinks.click( function() {
    var $this = $(this)
        target = $this.data('target')
    toggleMenu()
    $viewScreen.load(target + ".php")
    $this.data('clicked', true)

    if ($this.data('clicked') && target === "about") {
      activateAbout()
    }

    return false
  })

  function activateAbout() { 
    console.log('activated') 
  }
}
```

The console log works, and displays 'activated'. The pages do load.
All of my scripts compile and link correctly to each other. 
**However, when I include code that updates the target page CSS in the activateAbout() function, it doesn't work.** 
 For example:

```
$('body').css("background-color", "white")
```

in activateAbout() *works*, but calling/updating CSS elements in the chosen .php file *doesn't*, such as

```
$('.about p').css("color", "white")
// OR
$('.about').toggleClass('activate')
```

I have a feeling this has something to do with the order in which these files are loaded, but I'm not sure! Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is common phenomenon. The reason you are not able to apply the css is because, your content is loading after, you call `activateAbout()`. I would recommend to call `activateAbout()` once the `$viewScreen.load(target + ".php")` loads the data successfully. `jQuery.load()` supports callback too. Refer to the example usage at `https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp`. So, it should look like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $navLinks.click( function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        target = $this.data('target');
        toggleMenu();
        $viewScreen.load(target + ".php", function() {
            $this.data('clicked', true);
            if ($this.data('clicked') && target === "about") {
                activateAbout();
             }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
function activateAbout() {
    console.log('activated')
 }
```

Also there is a trick using `setTimeout` which you can execute after certain time, when the view is expected to be loaded like below

```
if ($this.data('clicked') && target === "about") {
    //The timeout period you can change accordingly
    setTimeout(activateAbout, 300);
}
```

The recommended way is first type solution. Hope this helps you!!

Comment: Yes! This is the solution I was looking for, helped me a lot. Thanks for the added setTimeout advice

Comment: Welcome @Miranda. Glad to know this helped you.